# Changing settings in NCache Manager doesn't apply

Tags: distributed-cache, ncache

As an example I apply Query Indexes and then start the cache. The API throws exception that indexes have not yet been applied.

Attached is the image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the top of the image ? It says *Untitled Project*

I think you have forgotten to click on *Apply Configuration*

See the image below to help you find the icon.

[image]

Always remember to click on *Apply Configuration* to actually apply the changes to the cache.

See [here](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/docs/ncache/help/apply-config.html) and [here](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/docs/ncache/help/hot-apply-config.html) for more info

Comment: Tried it. Works. Thanks